# Filter Nested JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

First, let me explain what I'm trying to accomplish...

I would like to take the data that I'm receiving from an API and filter it based on a certain value. I'll post the JSON below...

```
{ assetNo:
{ type: 'string',
 format: 'short-text',
 minLength: 0,
 maxLength: 100,
 description: 'Asset ID' },
 serialNo:
 { type: 'string',
 format: 'short-text',
 minLength: 0,
 maxLength: 100,
 description: 'Serial Number' },
 'item:model':
 { type: 'object',
 properties: { title: [Object], _id: [Object] },
 description: 'Model' },
 'location:location':
 { type: 'object',
 properties: { title: [Object], _id: [Object] },
 description: 'Location ID' },
 'item:status':
 { type: 'object',
 properties: { title: [Object], _id: [Object] },
 description: 'Status' },
 imei:
 { type: 'string',
 format: 'short-text',
 minLength: 0,
 maxLength: 100,
 description: 'IMEI' },
 hostName:
 { type: 'string',
 format: 'short-text',
 minLength: 0,
 maxLength: 100,
 description: 'Host Name' },
 staticIp:
 { type: 'string',
 format: 'short-text',
 minLength: 0,
 maxLength: 100,
 description: 'Static IP' },
 mac:
  { type: 'string',
 format: 'short-text',
 minLength: 0,
 maxLength: 100,
 description: 'MAC' },
 macFriendlyName:
 { type: 'string',
 format: 'short-text',
 minLength: 0,
 maxLength: 100,
 description: 'MAC Friendly Name' },
 manufacturerWarrantyEndDate:
 { type: 'string',
 format: 'date-time',
 description: 'Manufacturer Warranty End Date' },
 notes:
 { type: 'string',
 format: 'long-text',
 minLength: 0,
 maxLength: 100,
 description: 'Notes' },
 _id:
 { type: 'string',
 format: 'BSON ObjectID',
 example: '12344ac4ac34d504212c0db6' } }
```

As you can see, there are a few nested objects... Flattened out, the data looks like this...

```
    {
      "assetNo": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "short-text",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 100,
        "description": "Asset ID"
      },
      "serialNo": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "short-text",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 100,
        "description": "Serial Number"
      },
      "item:model": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "short-text",
            "description": "title"
          },
          "_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "BSON ObjectID",
            "example": "12344ac4ac34d504212c0db6"
          }
        },
        "description": "Model"
      },
      "location:location": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "short-text",
            "description": "title"
          },
          "_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "BSON ObjectID",
            "example": "12344ac4ac34d504212c0db6"
          }
        },
        "description": "Location ID"
      },
      "item:status": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "short-text",
            "description": "title"
          },
          "_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "BSON ObjectID",
            "example": "12344ac4ac34d504212c0db6"
          }
        },
        "description": "Status"
      },
      "imei": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "short-text",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 100,
        "description": "IMEI"
      },
      "hostName": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "short-text",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 100,
        "description": "Host Name"
      },
      "staticIp": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "short-text",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 100,
        "description": "Static IP"
      },
      "mac": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "short-text",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 100,
        "description": "MAC"
      },
      "macFriendlyName": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "short-text",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 100,
        "description": "MAC Friendly Name"
      },
      "manufacturerWarrantyEndDate": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date-time",
        "description": "Manufacturer Warranty End Date"
      },
      "notes": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "long-text",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 100,
        "description": "Notes"
      },
      "_id": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "BSON ObjectID",
        "example": "12344ac4ac34d504212c0db6"
      }
    }
```

How can I iterate through this data, flatten out the nested objects, and return only the key/val for 'type'?

For example... I'd like to return something that looks like this...

```
    {
      "assetNo": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "serialNo": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "location:location": {
        "type": "object",
            "type": "string",
          },
          "_id": {
            "type": "string",
      },
      "item:status": {
        "type": "object",
            "type": "string",
          },
          "_id": {
            "type": "string",
          }
      },
      "imei": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "hostName": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "staticIp": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "mac": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "macFriendlyName": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "manufacturerWarrantyEndDate": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "notes": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "_id": {
        "type": "string",
      }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use recursive function, because you do not know how nested the object will be. Check out this function.

```
const mapObj = (data) => {
    return Object.keys(data).reduce((agg, ele) => {
        if (ele === 'type') {
            agg.type = data[ele];
        } else if (typeof data[ele] === 'object') {
            agg[ele] = mapObj(data[ele]);
        }
        return agg;
    }, new Object());
};
```

Call this function with your JSON and it will do the trick.